# CSS body background position right bottom not working

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I am trying to place a background image in the background of the `body` tag using `right bottom` but for some reason the image almost totally appears out of view. Besides a solution I would like to also understand why this is not working as I expected. I changed the combination to other settings like `left bottom` and still image is out of view.

The image is this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpKuw.jpg?s=328&g=1

```css
body {
 background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpKuw.jpg?s=328&g=1);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  right bottom; 
}
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: Your body element is 16 pixels tall (8px top and bottom margins). The background image position is correct.

Comment: Add `body { min-height: 100vh; }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `body` doesn't have enough `height` yet to get the image rendered as expected, so you can to this in a couple ways:

- set  `html, body { height:100%}`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpKuw.jpg?s=328&g=1) no-repeat right bottom;

}
```

- set  `body { height:100vh}`

```css
body {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpKuw.jpg?s=328&g=1) no-repeat right bottom;
  height: 100vh
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Than why does using `background-image` with `background-repeat: repeat` title the image with no height added to the `body` tag?

Comment: because as per  [W3 specs says:](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-repeat) `The image is repeated in this direction as often as needed to cover the background painting area. `

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is nothing in the `body`, there is just not enough space for the image to appear.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/hhs8jvgr/